# Getting the name of an empty column with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of image paths stored in a table like this:

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    |ID           |pimg0        |pimg1         |pimg2         |
    +-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
    |1            |path/to/img0 |path/to/img1  |              |
    +---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
    |2            |path/to/img0 |path/to/img1  |              |
    +---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

and I want to get the table name of the empty field so I can put a new entry into it.

I have tried nesting IFNULL() commands in the mysql query, which didn't work:

```
    IFNULL(pimg0, IFNULL(pimg1, IFNULL(pimg2, IFNULL(pimg3, IFNULL(pimg4, IFNULL(pimg5))))))
```

I have also tried some case blocks which didn't work. Ideally I would like my query to return "pimg2" in the above scenario, but if it was to return "pimg1" I could easily increment it.

EDIT: Edited the table above, to clarify.

Comment: Just a semantic thing, would it not be easier to store just the file name instead of the path/to/file/name.jpg? 

That way you could update your code if you need to change the file structure, without having to edit the data of every row in your database.

Comment: Yeah, I actually do just have the image name in the db, the file path is compiled with php when the loop is run.

Comment: And.. you wanna get the column name with an empty/null value, is that correct? Then what, perform an update to fill it up? Will the value be based on the column name?

Comment: I want to get either the column name or a value defining the increment of the column, so in this case, I would like a return of either "pimg2", or "2" I'll use that information to do an sql update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing one of the pain points of [repeating groups across columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_across_columns), which is a violation of First Normal Form.

The pain goes away if you normalize, by creating a child table with *one* column for image path, and adding multiple rows when you have multiple images.

```
CREATE TABLE Images (
  image_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  owner_id INT NOT NULL, -- references `id` in your original table
  pimg      VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO Images (owner_id, pimg) VALUES 
 (1, 'path/to/img0'), (1, 'path/to/img1'), 
 (2, 'path/to/img2'), (2, 'path/to/img3');
```

Structuring a database in this way makes it easier to do many tasks:

- Insert a new image by INSERT a new row; no need to find the blank column.
- Add a fourth or a fifth image to a given `owner_id`.
- Search a given image and report which `owner_id` owns it.
- Count images per `owner_id`.
- Avoid duplicates.

Comment: That is fantastic and would have prevented me ever having this problem. I solved the problem below but this is a way better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, 'pimg0'
FROM table WHERE pimg0 is null
UNION
SELECT id, 'pimg1'
FROM table WHERE pimg1 is null
UNION
SELECT id, 'pimg2'
FROM table WHERE pimg2 is null
```

Comment: There's a typo in your second WHERE clause. I think it should be pimg1

Answer (score 1):

I do like the MySQL answer provided by Zohaib above, but if you want to go jeroen's route and do this in PHP you would want something along the lines of:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
 $result = mysql_query or die();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
      foreach($row as $key => $val)
      {
           if(empty($val))
           {
                //DoStuff
                print "Empty $key in ID: {$row['id']}<br/>";
           }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can probably do it in sql, I would personally do it in php; just get the whole row and loop through the fields until you find an empty result.

That way it will keep on working automatically if you decide to add some additional columns in the future.

Comment: I think you may be right, php is much easier to work with than mysql anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
IFNULL(concat('t0|',pimg0), IFNULL(concat('t1|',pimg1), IFNULL(concat('t2|',pimg2), IFNULL(concat('t3|',pimg3), IFNULL(concat('t4|',pimg4), IFNULL(concat('t5|',pimg5)))))))
```

Then use "|" as separator to get value and column

**ADDING**

MySql can give you directly the value and column name

```
select 
IFNULL(pimg0, IFNULL(pimg1, IFNULL(pimg2, IFNULL(pimg3, IFNULL(pimg4, IFNULL(pimg5)))))) as value,    
SUBSTRING_INDEX( IFNULL(concat('t0|',pimg0), IFNULL(concat('t1|',pimg1), IFNULL(concat('t2|',pimg2), IFNULL(concat('t3|',pimg3), IFNULL(concat('t4|',pimg4), IFNULL(concat('t5|',pimg5))))))), '|',1) as columnname
```

Comment: sorry I misunderstanding the rquest.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it.

```
$sql="
   SELECT
   *
   FROM 
   table
   WHERE
   ID = $id
   ";

$query=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$array=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
   $imageentry = "pimg".$i;
   if($array[$imageentry]=='' or $array[$imageentry]=null){
   $nextimagenumber = $i;
   break;
}
}
echo $nextimagenumber;
```

This returns the next number of the empty "pimg" field, even if there is a gap in the table, so running it on a table like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|pimg0          |pimg1          |pimg2          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|img0           |               |img2           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

returns "2"